# Selenium Chrome keeps opening on the existing chrome session

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My team and I recently noticed that our web automation with selenium and chromedriver stopped working. When we invoke a chrome browser instance using python selenium, we would get an error:

```
Opening in existing browser session.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Programs\DMT Web Apps\DMT\github\taf-rapid-layeredapps-automation-robot\rapidrtcautomation\tests\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "C:\Users\William.Tan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\William.Tan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 105, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\William.Tan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 288, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\William.Tan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 381, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\William.Tan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 442, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\William.Tan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Based on observation we know that chrome is not reachable because it did not instantiate a new browser window, instead it keeps opening a tab on existing chrome window instance..

The code is very short and simple since we've been trying to debug this as well:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--remote-allow-origins=*')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Anyone have any idea what could be causing it, I'm pretty sure it's on our side, I've looked at firewall and chrome and chromedriver versions. Only happens with chrome as well, edge and firefox are fine...

We've tried removing firewall, updating chrome, adding the options:

```
options.add_argument('--remote-allow-origins=*')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
```

Comment: solved error? what code use?  I tried everything and it says the same thing. :(

Comment: Sadly no. We've moved over to using edge for development as the issue only happens on our corporate machines. Luckily edge is chromium based so it behaves similar

Answer (score 1):

same thing happened to our team, scripts were working fine for 5 months then suddenly everything stopped working because it opens on existing session. Didnt solve the problem but found a work around. We now have to close all our tabs before running the script and added the following options. I dont think the remote debugging had anything to do with it, as i previously did not have it in the script and it was running fine.

```
        #Chrome Config
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    web = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    web.maximize_window()
    web.switch_to.window(web.window_handles[-1])
    web.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `--remote-debugging-port=9222` option from your script, it can open a new tab in an existing Chrome window instead of starting a new instance which could be your problem.

so it should be like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--remote-allow-origins=*')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Also, I have used the `options` argument instead because `chrome_options` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

When initiating a new browser instances using the identical `--user-data-dir` it will open within the current browser context, as per Chrome's design. To witness this behavior directly, initiate the browser via command line without employing Selenium:

```bash
google-chrome --no-first-run --user-data-dir=/some/dir
```

Execute this command in a separate terminals and review the resulting output.

**Solution**

Run multiple Chrome instances with different `--user-data-dir` options or delete this two files before each start:

1. `/your/profile/dir/SingletonLock` - prevents run of multiple instances simultaneously
2. `/your/profile/dir/SingletonSocket` - used when an option `--remote-debugging-port` is present